# Detecting letters using pyocr(tesseract) on a grid

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract

I have successfully used pyocr with tesseract to detect text on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8OwI.png)

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

# Tools
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
    print("No OCR tool found")
    sys.exit(1)
tool = tools[0]
print("Will use tool '%s'" % (tool.get_name()))

# Language
langs = tool.get_available_languages()
lang = langs[0]
print("Will use lang '%s'" % (lang))

# Get text
txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open('1.jpg'),
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)

print(txt)
```

Unfortunately when I try this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJKc5.jpg), I dont get any result at all.
My plan is to have an array such as (R, U, S, L)

Answer (score 2):

Your `jpeg` background is too **fitfully**, try
Read about: [libpillowfight](https://github.com/openpaperwork/libpillowfight#stroke-width-transformation)

```
img_out = pillowfight.unpaper_noisefilter(img_in)
```

or

```
img_out = pillowfight.swt(img_in, output_type=pillowfight.SWT_OUTPUT_ORIGINAL_BOXES)
```

Beside this I suggest to use **Black &White** image only.